# An alternative to npm async module?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, npm

Today I'm using parse.com and I would like to perform an asynchronous programming in javascript. I found the npm async module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-async
But parse.com doesn't accept npm modules. Would you know any alternative to async module for parse.com ?

Thanking you in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess one of the most famous libraries to perform asynchronous programming in JavaScript is [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async). (You can see one example of its popularity by the number of stars it has on GitHub)

It is packaged as an npm module, but the code is directly available too, and does not rely on npm at all (not even on Node.js by the way).

You can download the latest version (master branch) on GitHub there: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js

Answer (score 0):

On this question I show a way to do an Async.each without the Async module

[Async in node without using the async module, is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308367/async-in-node-without-using-the-async-module-is-there-a-better-way)