# Async in node without using the async module, is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I need to perform the equivalent of the `async.eachSeries()` method, but I did not want to add a dependency such as `require('async')`.

So I came up with the implementation below, and I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
it 'String::start_Process_Capture_Console_Out', (done)->

    runTest = (testData,next)->
        name          = testData.process_Name
        parameter     = testData.process_Parameter
        expected_Data = testData.expected_Data
        name.start_Process_Capture_Console_Out parameter, (data)->
            data.assert_Is(expected_Data)
            next()

    runTests = (testsData, next)->
        if testsData.empty() 
            next() 
        else 
            runTest testsData.pop(), ()-> runTests(testsData, next)

    testsData = [
                    {process_Name: 'echo' , process_Parameter: 'hello'       , expected_Data:'hello\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'echo' , process_Parameter: ['hello','me'], expected_Data:'hello,me\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'git'  , process_Parameter: ['xyz'       ], expected_Data:'git: \'xyz\' is not a git command. See \'git --help\'.\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'ls'   , process_Parameter: '.'           , expected_Data:'LICENSE\nREADME.md\nindex.js\nnode_modules\npackage.json\nsrc\ntest\n' }
                ]    

    runTests(testsData, done)
```

For reference here are the `start_Process` and `start_Process_Capture_Console_Out` string prototype methods

```
String::start_Process = (args...)->
  args ?= []
  return child_process.spawn(@.str(),args)


String::start_Process_Redirect_Console = (args...)->
  args ?= []
  childProcess = @.start_Process(args)
  childProcess.stdout.on 'data', (data)->console.log(data.str().trim())
  childProcess.stderr.on 'data', (data)->console.log(data.str().trim())
  return childProcess  

String::start_Process_Capture_Console_Out =  (args... , callback)->
    consoleData = ""
    childProcess = @.start_Process(args)
    childProcess.stdout.on 'data', (data)->consoleData+=data
    childProcess.stderr.on 'data', (data)->consoleData+=data
    childProcess.on 'exit', ()->
      callback(consoleData)
    return childProcess
```

One solution would be to add a prototype to the `Array` class, maybe called `async_Each_Series` so that we could just have:

```
    testsData = [
                    {process_Name: 'echo' , process_Parameter: 'hello'       , expected_Data:'hello\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'echo' , process_Parameter: ['hello','me'], expected_Data:'hello,me\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'git'  , process_Parameter: ['xyz'       ], expected_Data:'git: \'xyz\' is not a git command. See \'git --help\'.\n' }
                    {process_Name: 'ls'   , process_Parameter: '.'           , expected_Data:'LICENSE\nREADME.md\nindex.js\nnode_modules\npackage.json\nsrc\ntest\n' }
                ]    

   testsData.async_Each_Series(runTest, done)
```

Comment: It seems to me you have implemented [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback), not `each`?

Comment: By what criteria "better"? If you want to focus on mainability and readability, don't reinvent the wheel and just require `async`. There's no harm in that.

Comment: @Bergi yes I implemented eachSeries (going to update the post with the fix)

Answer (score 1):

the nodejs Array class already has a forEach method, but it does not take a callback

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach (i) ->
    console.log i
```

if you need the callback, write (js this time)

```
function applyVisitor( data, visitor, next ) {
    // ...
}
```

Or you can also avoid dependencies and cut-and-past copy the relevant code into yours.

(Edit: in short, yes, there is a better way -- write a general-purpose iterator and use
it for the these tests, do not write special-purpose loop just for this.)

My implementation of applyVisitor
(also in https://npmjs.org/package/aflow)

```
/**
 * Repeatedly call func until it signals stop (returns truthy) or err.
 * Func is passed just a standard callback taking err and ret.
 * Returns via its callback the truthy value from func.
 */
function repeatUntil( func, callback ) {
    'use strict';

    callback = callback || function() {};

    function _loop( func, callback, callDepth ) {
        try {
            func( function(err, stop) {
                if (err || stop) return callback(err, stop);
                if (callDepth < 40) _loop(func, callback, callDepth + 1);
                else setImmediate(function() { _loop(func, callback, 0); });
            } );
        }
        catch (e) { callback(e); }
    }
    // note: 2.5x faster if callback is passed in to _loop vs pulled from closure

    _loop(func, callback, 0);
}


/**
 * visitor pattern: present all items to the visitor function.
 * Returns just error status, no data; to capture the results,
 * wrapper the visitor function.
 */
function applyVisitor( dataItems, visitorFunction, callback ) {
    'use strict';

    if (!Array.isArray(dataItems)) {
        return callback(new Error("expected a data array, but got " + typeof data));
    }

    var next = 0;
    repeatUntil(
        function applyFunc(cb) {
            if (next >= dataItems.length) return cb(null, true);
            visitorFunction(dataItems[next++], function(err) {
                cb(err, err);
            });
        },
        function(err, stop) {
            callback(err);
        }
    );
}
```